# using separate_rows in tidyr over many columns when some columns do not have delimiters

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split, tidyr

I have the following mock dataset:

```
A <- c("Acura", "BMW", "Toyota", NA)
B <- c("1993;2004;2010", "2013", "2003;2011", NA)
C <- c("Blue;Black;Gold", "Silver", NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(A = A, B = B, C = C)
```

So the data frame looks like this:

```
> df
         A                B                 C
  1  Acura   1993;2004;2010   Blue;Black;Gold
  2    BMW             2013            Silver
  3 Toyota        2003;2011              <NA>
  4   <NA>             <NA>              <NA>
```

I would like to expand the data set to multiple rows so it looks like this:

```
> new_df
          A         B          C
  1   Acura      1993       Blue
  2   Acura      2004      Black
  3   Acura      2010       Gold
  4     BMW      2013     Silver
  5  Toyota      2003       <NA>
  6  Toyota      2011       <NA>
  7    <NA>      <NA>       <NA>
```

I have tried using tidyr::separate_rows however I get this error because separate rows needs the same number of delimiters in each column by row.  This means, row 3 (A = Toyota) is a problem, because there is an NA in column C for that row and not something like "NA;NA".  This is the command and error I receive:

```
df %>% separate_rows(B, C, sep = ";", convert = TRUE)
   Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.

df[c(1:2,4),] %>% separate_rows(B, C, sep = ";", convert = TRUE)
      A    B      C
1 Acura 1993   Blue
2 Acura 2004  Black
3 Acura 2010   Gold
4   BMW 2013 Silver
5  <NA>   NA   <NA>

df[c(3),] %>% separate_rows(B, C, sep = ";", convert = TRUE)
    Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.
```

Can someone help how to achieve new_df?!

Comment: Replace `NA` with a random string, then `separate_rows` and then replace back by `NA`?

Comment: I've tried that but it has nothing to do that it is an NA.. it has to do that there should be the same number of elements.. for example it would were if there was "NA;NA" in column C, row 3 but not a single "NA"

Comment: Can you check your version of `tidyr`? Run `packageVersion("tidyr")`. I am on the development version and can't reproduce the error, it works as expected for me. It may also work properly on the latest version.

Comment: @CalumYou I'm using version 0.8.2 of tidyr

Comment: Try updating to 0.8.3 and see if it works

Comment: @CalumYou I updated to 0.8.3 and the error still exists

Comment: @Sheila Hey... Calum's solution works now with the package. Try checking the command and accept the answer so that future learners would know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the easiest solution might be installing the development version of `tidyr` (0.8.3.9000) since it seems to be fixed there. Use `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")` to achieve that.

However, for a workaround for those who can't update or don't want to use a prerelease version of the package, we can count the required number of separators in each row and fill the missing values in the columns with separators. That lets `separate_rows` work and creates empty strings, which we then replace back with `NA`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
A <- c("Acura", "BMW", "Toyota", NA)
B <- c("1993;2004;2010", "2013", "2003;2011", NA)
C <- c("Blue;Black;Gold", "Silver", NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(A = A, B = B, C = C, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
  mutate(seps = str_pad("", width = str_count(B, ";"), pad = ";")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(B, C), ~ coalesce(., seps)) %>%
  separate_rows(B, C, sep = ";") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(B, C), ~ str_replace(., "^$", NA_character_))
#>        A    B      C seps
#> 1  Acura 1993   Blue   ;;
#> 2  Acura 2004  Black   ;;
#> 3  Acura 2010   Gold   ;;
#> 4    BMW 2013 Silver     
#> 5 Toyota 2003   <NA>    ;
#> 6 Toyota 2011   <NA>    ;
#> 7   <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In the latest `tidyr` it can be done easily

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% separate_rows(B, C, sep = ';')
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  A      B     C     
  <chr>  <chr> <chr> 
1 Acura  1993  Blue  
2 Acura  2004  Black 
3 Acura  2010  Gold  
4 BMW    2013  Silver
5 Toyota 2003  NA    
6 Toyota 2011  NA    
7 NA     NA    NA
```